# Is it good practice to duplicate the connections to the grandparent in the parent and son in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

[image: Scheme 1]

[image: Scheme 2]

I've seen different database designs in different projects. Some of them claim that from son to grandparent one should go through the parent (intuitively correct); in others there is a lot of duplication.

Which is right?

Comment: If your each entity has same attribute then go for Single table which will hold person and column for parent of the person(ID). You can then use the hierarchy queries to find out son-parent-gretParent from single table. no duplication and standard way of doing it

Comment: I don't think that there is a right one and it's more up to personal preference. The most correct way could be the first one, as you don't duplicate data. However you could say the second one as this is a bit easier/faster if you have to work with son & great-parent a lot. But IMO neither one is wrong.

Comment: The second solution is more dangerous since errors (the parent and son that have a different greatparent id) must be checked and blocked at the application level, since they cannot be checked at the database level.

Comment: child/parent/grandparent is not a particularly useful concept in a relational DBMS. A FK constraint says subrows appear elsewhere uniquely, ie that participants in an association/relationship/relation participate elsewhere once. Where that is so & isn't implied by other declarations, delcare it. FK constraints are transitive. FKs, PKs, UNIQUE & other constraints don't record, they block invalid DB states. Design according to whatever published information modelling & DB design method you are following. You are following one, right? (Which?) PS Your son FK should be (father,grandfather).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text. PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & seldom asking for what the asker actually wants.

Comment: Your post is not clear about the constraints involved with the sort of family heirarchy you are talking about. child/parent/grandparent involves a child having more than 1 parent but son/father/grandfather does not. It's not clear why your son has only 1 parent & 1 grandparent. I suspect that in this post those be father & grandfather, since there's only 1 person each generation. Since you are asking about how to appropriately constrain in a DB design you need to tell us very clearly what case(s) you are addressing & your chosen words & description are too vague.

Comment: Indeed this post asking about some situation a beginner happens to notice or to try to characterize is a typical example of asking about something that is not relevant because you should be **following your chosen published information modelling & DB design method** & asking 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are 1st stuck. Also when your case is very clear it will already have been asked many times. Though mostly not usefully, because an answer is just rewriting a published method that isn't identified & isn't reflected in the question, which is thus unclear & unfocused.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
[Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [ask] [Help] PS "intuitively" is not helpful. "best" means nothing in particular. Nor does "duplication" or "a lot". For specific meanings duplication isn't per se bad or unavoidable. Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Son` table, column `ParentID` also determines `GreatParentID`.  This violates [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

All else being equal, implementing normal form is a reasonable idea.